# Whois History resources authentic source

Tags: phishing, websites, dns-domain, domain, whois

I have couple of doubts related to Whois records.
For a particulate domain...

> How authentic are the Whois records?

As per my research the records are not permissible in courts (or at least would not be considered primary evidence). As I can register a domain providing false information (or in someone else' name) and so, not considered authentic.

> Who is responsible for authenticity of these records?

I guess it should be the job of Registrar to validate the information provided. On the other hand I am certain if one is buying a domain for personal use no verification is done(Registrar sell it like popcorn). Does that also apply for buying a domain for business or in the name of business.

> Who would stop someone from even registering f4c3b00k.com (assuming availability) **using following information?**

```
Registrant Name: Mark Zuckerberg
Registrant Organization: Facebook, Inc.
Registrant Street: 1601 Willow Rd 
Registrant City: Menlo Park
```

*Please note I am not talking about the situation where facebook would come to know about this domain and initiate UDRP. I am interested in knowing any controls that are placed at the time of registering a domain by ICANN/ Registry/ Registrar*

> What are whois history records?

Do they contain information on ownership of certain domain.
If yes, certain.domain has 2 Whois history records. Does this mean certain.domain has been transferred to other person or in other words registrant information has been changed one time

> Which should be the accurate source for Whois/ Whois history records? The registry itself or the registrar?

Also please provide some good resouce/link on searching for Whoi History records. Most sites offer it as a paid service while others providing varying information.

Comment: In fact, what actually you are looking for ? Free history records for domain registration ?  Or you want to get the records from hundred thousands of domain registrar around the world?

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answer asked can be founded from [wikipedia page on WHOIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WHOIS) .

> What are whois history records?

There is no clear obligation specification in ICANN that mentioned all registration history must be kept. So there are some third party services such domaintools attempt to log the info from whois protocol and provide the history as services. Such services are mostly paid services because whois retrieval has  a hard limit.  Company that doing this is using various evasive mechanism (e.g. proxy, vpn, etc) which is costly to collect.

> Which should be the accurate source for Whois/ Whois history records?
>   The registry itself or the registrar?

If you go through the WHOIS wikipedia page, you will notice GDPR itself already render WHOIS record "obsolete", you really don't get much WHOIS info from most EU  country TLD.

Ironically, the non-free-world China TLD WHOIS (*.cn) will give you more info due to real name registration policies from China government.

Comment: What is written and what is in practice is different thing. Incomplete responce